# Sql Server Performance Not What I'd Expect

Tags: sql-server

I've got a very simple one table query that takes many seconds to complete. I'm baffled.  When I change from select top to 50 instead of 200 it goes much faster.  The table has about a million rows.

I've got indexes on all the columns mentioned.

```
SELECT TOP 50 dbo.EmailDetails.Id,
FROM dbo.EmailDetails WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendStatus = 'NEEDTOSEND' OR
  dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendStatus = 'NEEDTOTEXT') AND
  dbo.EmailDetails.EmailDetailsTopicId IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendPriority,
     dbo.EmailDetails.Id DESC
```

The Plan Generate is:

[image]

and the Full DDL is:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.EmailDetails (
      Id int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
      AttendeesId int NOT NULL,
      SponsorListContactId int NULL,
      MessageUniqueId nvarchar(512) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      EmailSendStatus nvarchar(16) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      EmailSendStartTime datetime NULL,
      EmailSendFinishTime datetime NULL,
      EmailSendLogMessage nvarchar(max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      Subject nvarchar(2048) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      BodyText nvarchar(max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      SentDateTime datetime NULL,
      EmailFrom nvarchar(128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      EmailTo nvarchar(128) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      EmailDetailsTopicId int NULL,
      EmailDetailsGuid uniqueidentifier NULL,
      EmailReadCount int NULL,
      EmailReadDate datetime NULL,
      EmailSendStatusChange datetime NULL,
      EmailSendPriority int NULL,
      TextTo varchar(64) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
      CONSTRAINT EmailDetails_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Id)
        WITH (
          PAD_INDEX = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
          ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    )
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_AttendeesIds_idx ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (AttendeesId)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_idx ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (EmailDetailsGuid)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_idx2 ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (EmailDetailsTopicId)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_idx3 ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (SentDateTime)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_priority_status_idx4 ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (EmailSendPriority, EmailSendStatus)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_SentStatus_idx ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (EmailSendStatus)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_topicid_attendeeid ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (EmailDetailsTopicId, AttendeesId)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO

    CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX EmailDetails_topicid_sponsorcontactid_idx ON dbo.EmailDetails
      (EmailDetailsTopicId, SponsorListContactId)
    WITH (
      PAD_INDEX = OFF,
      DROP_EXISTING = OFF,
      STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
      SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF,
      ONLINE = OFF,
      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON,
      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
    ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question about it?

Comment: You know what a query plan is? EXPORT IT (.sqlplan) and then we can help.

Comment: Faster at 200 was just probably rows / indexes in memory.  50 versus 200 it still has to sort.

Comment: It's perhaps significant that the estimated row count shown in your screenshot is 1. Are the statistics on the tables/indexes up to date?

Comment: same thing but easier to read WHERE dbo.EmailDetails.EmailSendStatus in ('NEEDTOSEND', 'NEEDTOTEXT')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using `SELECT TOP x` together with `ORDER BY` is recommended in general to ensure the same results every time, the `ORDER BY` will sort the entire result set, and only then the TOP x is taken from it.

I wonder what you'd see if you do `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead of `SELECT TOP x`: probably a rather high number?

And while using indexes guarantees fast sorting, there is **no** index that covers the exact ORDER BY of this query. On top of that, getting the fields for the WHERE and SELECT clauses requires going into the datapages which are probably spread out all over disk. To optimize for just this query you could add the WHERE- and ORDER BY- and SELECT-fields to a new index (in that order), of course without duplicates. It would make for a rather big index, which could slow down inserts/updates, but it will also make the SELECT very fast because then the whole query can be satisfied using just the index, without going into the datapages.

Comment: thanks everyone for the input.  I'll post the plan when I get back to my desk and do the count(*) test also.

Comment: doing select count(*) is very fast (instant) so I assume it's not an index problem.  As i reduce the number of columns I'm retrieving, it gets faster and faster.  I assume this means my data must be scattered around the disk?  Anyway to get the last entries to all be close to each other?  The top records are always the 10 or 20 thousand I just inserted.

Comment: The value of count(\*) gives an indication of the amount of work that ORDER BY has to do before the TOP x can be taken, especially if there is no single index that covers the ORDER BY fields. The speed of count(\*) itself is not so relevant, and it is even possible that the ORDER BY is skipped if count(\*) is requested and no other fields. What's more important is to create an index more or less as I indicated.

Comment: one thing I did not mention is that if I take out from my select everything but the primary key, the result returns pretty fast (less than a second) vs if I leave the other fields in it takes 23 seconds.  Does that mean the overhead of the select with the order by is OK?  In enterprise manager, any way to see time of query more granular ten one second? -thanks

Comment: Just remember that datapage access is relatively slow, esp. with a conventional HDD. Also, the nvarchar(max) columns are stored in yet another place on disk, making access again slower. The more fields it can get directly from the index to fulfill your request, the faster it will be. And you can use SET STATISTICS TIME ON to see query statistics.